# Как собрать проект gulp'ом так, чтобы require зависимости встраивались в файл куда они загружаються?

Tags: gulp, build, require

файлы проекта:

- **index.html**:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <script src="test.js "></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>
          Hallo World!
      </h1>
  </body>
  ```
- **test.js**:

  ```
  "use strict";
  var superagent = require('superagent');
  superagent.get('/testRequest');
  ```

Проблема в том что в браузере нельзя вызвать require.

Посоветуйте решение, пожалуйста.

Comment: http://browserify.org/

Comment: спасибо) именно то что нужно, но я уже решил встpаиванием библиотеки в index.html)